# Python path issue with pickled class

Tags: python, path, pickle

I have a class call Monkey, defined in `root/ook/monkey.py`.  Another script, let's call it  do_things.py pickles instances of Monkey objects.  The script do_things.py looks like:

```
import monkey
[...]
inst = monkey.Monkey()
[...]
data = cPickle.dumps(inst)
```

Now, I have another script called `root/eek/fubar.py` that looks like this:

```
import ook/monkey
[...]
inst = cPickle.loads(data)
```

Where `data` is the same pickled as was in do_things.py in both cases.  Now, this unpickling fails because the class Monkey is not found.  In this script, it is called ook.Monkey.monkey and not monkey.Monkey.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your import in the second file from `import ook.monkey` to `from ook import monkey`.

Answer (score 1):

The name "Monkey" in the global variables of the running module has to reference the same "Monkey" class  -

so, in your pickling module, do

```
import monkey
Monkey = monkey.Monkey
```

or just:

```
from monkey import Monkey
```

(from the snippedts you pasted you already do one of these, or the line `inst = Monkey()` would not work)

on your unpikcling module, do the same

```
import ook/monkey
Monkey = ook.monkey.Monkey
```

(at module level)